# Is ambient temperature a continuous function

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, home-experiment

Following the standard topology examples of [Borsuk–Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), did someone checked experimentally that `temperature is indeed a continuous function on the Earth's surface?`

Comment: Why would the temperature on Earth be considered a function on $S^n$? The atmosphere has non-zero thickness and it is in contact with both the Earth itself and outer space.

Comment: @Slereah When they say "the temperature on the Earth's surface", that should be taken literally - the temperature on the 2-dimensional manifold that corresponds to the ground/water level.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible to check experimentally. In order to experimentally check that a function is continuous, you would have to be able to make measurements that are infinitely close together, which isn't possible.